# Unix Regex (ERE) for finding a lines with 4 or more numbers

Tags: regex, linux, unix

I've tried so many variations but none seem to work, I have no idea what I don't understand.

The last one I've tried is `(\<[[:digit:]]+\>.*){4,}`.
But it doesn't even find lines like `123 123 123 123`.
The input lines can be anything (even like `hello 123 my 1 name 2 is 3`).

I didn't specify it, sorry, but what I meant is: line "123 a2" has 1 number, line "1 2 3 45" has 4 numbers.

Comment: remove the boundaries `\<` `\>` and the `+` quantifier.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte it will catch line like "2 re2 43 r2q" which has 2 numbers

Comment: oh ok, could you show your command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is some problem with quantifying the pattern in your `grep` command. If the first number has more than one digits, and the others contain just one, your regex works. Else, it won't, see the [testing results](https://ideone.com/2Cpemx):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s="123 1 2 3  - works, the first number is two+ digits, the rest are one digits
1 2 3 45 - does not work, the first number is one-digit
14 2 3 4 - works
123 a2 - not output as expected as there is just one number
12 and one 1 more and 23 and 6 and some more 3546
hello 123 my 1 name 2 is 3 - output fine since the first number is three-digit and the rest are one digit"
 
grep -E '(\<[[:digit:]]+\>.*){4,}' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
123 1 2 3  - works, the first number is two+ digits, the rest are one digits
14 2 3 4 - works
hello 123 my 1 name 2 is 3 - output fine since the first number is three-digit and the rest are one digit
```

If you rewrite it without `{4,}` it works:

```sh
grep -E '\<[0-9]+\>.*\<[0-9]+\>.*\<[0-9]+\>.*\<[0-9]+\>' file
```

See [this online demo](https://ideone.com/FnylZ4).

You can use this `awk` in any environment, too:

```sh
awk '{cnt=0; for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) { if ($i ~ /^[0-9]+$/) { cnt++ } } }cnt>3' file
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/VPteq9). *Details*:

- `cnt=0` - set the `cnt` counter variable to `0`
- `for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) {...}` - iterate over all fields in the current record (=line)
- `if ($i ~ /^[0-9]+$/) { cnt++ } }` - if the field is made of digits increment `cnt`
- `cnt>3` - if `cnt` is larger than `3`, print the found record.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/VPteq9):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s="123  123  123  123 
1 2 3 45
1 3 5
hello 123 my 1 name 2 is 3" 

awk '{cnt=0; for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) { if ($i ~ /^[0-9]+$/) { cnt++ } } }cnt>3' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
123  123  123  123 
1 2 3 45
hello 123 my 1 name 2 is 3
```

Comment: Thank you, that is pretty smart, but I'd like to know how to do it using egrep.

Comment: @Plk I added some more testing of the `grep` command, and it seems like a bug to me.

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code. We need NOT to use loop here. This `awk` code is written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
awk -v FPAT='(^|[[:space:]]+)[0-9]+([[:space:]]+|$)' 'NF>3' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

- Using GNU `awk`'s option named `FPAT` to allow regex to make field separators.
- Using regex `(^|[[:space:]]+)[0-9]+([[:space:]]+|$)` to match either starting spaces followed by digits OR digits followed by spaces or ending of line.
- In main `awk` program checking condition `NF>3` which means if number of fields are greater than 3 then print that line.